# Menu em C que se move com as setas do teclado?

Tags: c, algoritmo

Vi uma vez um algoritmo em C onde na seleção de menu tinha uma "mini navegação" se é que posso chamar assim, onde usava as setas do teclado para navegar no menu e enter para selecionar a opção, fiquei curioso pra saber como fazer aquilo, alguém pode mostrar?
Grato!

Comment: No stackoverflow, nos ajudamos a consertar algum erro em códigos, ou tiramos duvidas sobre temas considerados importantes no escopo do site. Se você tiver algo pre pronto, ajudaria muito para te ajudar

Comment: @BrumazziDB Não tenho, como disse é uma curiosidade =/ não encontrei nada na internet sobre isso, gostaria de saber se preciso de alguma biblioteca ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Pesquisa por uma lib em C chamada "ncurses", é a única que eu conheço que faz isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encontrei uma maneira, porém só funciona com duas opções no menu =/

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define KEY_ESC 27
#define KEY_ENTER 13

void menu_draw();

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
     menu_draw();
     return 0;
}

void menu_draw ()
{
    int key = 0;
    while(1)
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n   ******** Menu Principal ********\n");
    printf("   *                              *\n");
    printf("   * %s Opcao 1                    *\n", (key == KEY_UP)? "Û": " ");
    printf("   * %s Opcao 2                    *\n", (key == KEY_DOWN)? "Û": " ");
    printf("   *                              *\n");
    printf("   ********************************\n");
    key = getch();

    if (key == KEY_ESC)
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: isto é a solução da pergunta ou uma nova dúvida?

Comment: Uma solução que encontrei pesquisando.

Comment: Entendi, você pode marcar como accept quando o sistema permitir. Estava parecendo uma nova dúvida no texto da resposta.

Comment: rsrs tranquilo amigo.